# Copying a stored procedure from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a central management database which collates some information and runs some dynamic SQL for various other tasks when a new database is restored into the environment. One of those tasks is going to be a bit complex to achieve through dynamic SQL so I had the idea of creating a master copy stored procedure in the central DB and copying that over to the new databases after they are restored.

I've seen a few examples of people trying to do that on here but I can't get anything to play ball.

Here's what i am trying to achieve conceptually, note that I'm trying to cater for potentially multiple stored procedures to be created in this way just for future proofing.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @DatabaseName nvarchar(200)
set @DatabaseName = 'TargetDatabase'

set @sql =  
 (
   SELECT definition + char(13) + 'GO' 
   FROM sys.sql_modules s 
   INNER JOIN sys.procedures p 
   ON [s].[object_id] = [p].[object_id] WHERE p.name LIKE '%mastercopy%'
)

exec @sql
```

Thanks

Comment: I should mention that I have of course been running this with a USE statement against the target database!!... set @sql = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@databasename) + ';' +

Comment: Well that looks right. Though I prefer to user Management Studio and the Tasks -> Generate Scripts feature. You could store the resulting SQL in a table somewhere and run that as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yeah that (generate scripts) option wont work for me as it's manual, and i'm going for full automation. Table might, will give that a bash...

Comment: Transactional replication can replicate stored procedure definitions as well as data. It's especially appropriate if there's a need to keep the procedure definitions in sync with the master. Automating a replication subscription is a bit more involved, though.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, probably overkill though :)

Comment: It depends on your scenario. We didn't use it until there were dozens of servers, each with their own little local tweaks to stored procedures, all supposed to be running the same software. Maintaining that without central management is... not fun. If your stored procedure is only ever going to run once, though, then yes, it's overkill.

Comment: Yeah its a one time thing, the SP will drop FKs, truncate tables and reinstate keys - effectively flattening all transactional data so we have a lightweight database containing just master data that can be used for test purposes, so it will run once per database restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating `dynamic` script you could use one script with all the `procedures` that you want to create (you can script all the procs you want using 2 click in `SSMS`), you then run this script manually in the context of the database where you want to create these procedures or by passing the file with this script to `sqlcmd` with `-i` and passing the correct database name with `-d`.

Here [Use the sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2014) you can see the examples.

Comment: Thanks yes had considered this, and as the feature is already going to be enabled for other parts of the automation project there's no reason i couldn't do that. I was trying to avoid it because i wanted everything to be contained within the database so we can pick up and move it - but on reflection, we still can - if we automate the creation of the scripts on the file system prior to their execution each time!